# Error Adding Odoo Module: "No module found in repository"

Tags: python, module, odoo

I'm trying to upload my custom module to Odoo, but it keeps showing this same error:

```
No module found in repository ssh://git@github.com/ezert/planteagua-custom-fonts.git#16.0.
Each module needs to be in a separate folder at the root of the repository, even if there is only one module.
If you have all the files of your module at the root of your repository, you need to create a new folder with the name of your module and move all the files in it.
```

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... Isn't the module inside a folder at the repository root?

My repository link: https://github.com/ezert/planteagua-custom-fonts

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your module name is ```planteaqua-custom-fonts```; but in your git repo, it's ```plante_agua_custom_fonts```.

Comment: @ewokx Hi. Thank you for your response, but I've just figured out what was the real problem: I named it '__manfest__.py' instead of '__manifest__.py' xD It's working now

Answer (score 0):

The error was so simple...

I named it '**manfest**.py' instead of '**manifest**.py'

*I'm relieved this is working now but feeling ridiculous at the same time* xD